# how can I know whether an android app widget is in background

Tags: android, android-appwidget

I do not want to update UI of my app widget when it go to background(you can not see it), how can I know an app widget is in background?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot detect whether or not your homescreen widget it currently visible. There is an open bug report requesting this [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=5529&q=reporter%3amark.r.baird&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars).

At best, you could check to see if the homescreen (or any launcher in general) is visible:

```
public boolean isHomeShowing(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
    ArrayList<string> homeList = new ArrayList<string>();
    for(ResolveInfo info : this.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent, 0)){
        homeList.add(info.activityInfo.packageName);
    }

    ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager)getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        for (RunningTaskInfo t : am.getRunningTasks(1)) {
            if (t != null && t.numRunning > 0) {
                ComponentName cn = t.baseActivity;
                if (cn == null)
                   continue;
                else
                   if (homeList.contains(cn.getPackageName())) return true;
            }
        }
    return false;
}
```